# Why am I failing to iterate a vector using a C++11 range-based for loop?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator, c++98

```
std::vector<std::string> endpointLSRKey;

for(auto it = endpointLSRKey.begin(); it != endpointLSRKey.end(); ++it) {
        lsr->setItem(0, "", *it, address);
    }
```

then  get an error says that "auto" has changed the meanings in c++11, remove it!

so I change it like this:

```
for(std::string& str : endpointLSRKey){
        lsr->setItem(0, "", str, address);
    }
```

Then got an error say "range-based 'for' loops are not allowed in C++98 mode"

Totally confused, how to iterate it??

any why sometime it is c++11 and sometime it is c++98?

Comment: It appears that you are not compiling in C++11 mode. In C++98, auto has a (mostly useless) meaning that has been removed, and it also doesn't have range-based for loops. This implies that you are compiling in C++98 mode, not C++11 mode.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  If it's GCC (and I think clang too), add the flag `-std=c++0x`

Comment: what compiler, what settings?

Comment: @sharth then how should I do the iteration in c++98mode? thanks

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = endpointLSRKey.begin(); ...`

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you need to set your compiler into C++11 mode. The error message:

> "range-based 'for' loops are not allowed in C++98 mode"

points this out.

The way you do this depend on your compiler.

When you see this message:

> get an error says that "auto" has changed the meanings in c++11

Your compiler is still in C++98/03 mode. The keyword `auto` exists in C++03, but it has no meaning in most cases because by default variables to into automatic storage. (You can make a variable go into static storage by marking it with `static`. That is, `auto` is to `static` as `signed` is to `unsigned` (in C++98/03).

Because this meaning isn't really useful in C++98/03, and because the meaning changes in C++11, a compiler in C++03 mode might complain about use of `auto` with a warning. If you treat warnings as errors, then that gets turned into an error. Thus the message you are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

> how should I do the iteration in c++98mode?

Either

```
for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = endpointLSRKey.begin(); it != endpointLSRKey.end(); ++it) {
    lsr->setItem(0, "", *it, address);
}
```

or

```
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < endpointLSRKey.size(); ++i) {
    lsr->setItem(0, "", endpointLSRKey[i], address);
}
```